# Telerik RadGrid maintain scroll position after row selection

Tags: scrollbar, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a RadGrid that has a WebUserControl for each row of the grid to allow the user to edit that row.  When I click the edit button to expand the row (this opens up a .ascx control within the grid for that row), it always scrolls to the top of the page.  The user then has to scroll down to find the row they selected with the row expanded to begin editing that row.

I found in another post that adding `RadGrid1.ClientSettings.AllowKeyboardNavigation = true;` prior to data binding the grid helps to maintain scroll position.  This kind of works and you only have to scroll down one click of the mouse wheel to find the row to edit; not good enough.

I also have set `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback=“true"` on the aspx page.

I also have set on the RadGrid itself under client settings `SaveScrollPosition=“true"`.

What I'd like to see is the page not move at all when the user clicks on edit for the given row.  I would like to maintain the scroll position on the page.

Can this be accomplished?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out why my grid always scrolled to the top.  It was my fault.  I wanted the user to see any message from the WebUserControl when control pass back to the parent page.  The RadGrid1.ClientSettings.Scrolling.ScrollTop = 0; was the issue.

I had the following code listed:

```
    private void DisplayMessage()
    {
        // Display any messages from RadGrid2 that occurred in WebUserControl
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Session["LabelUpdated"])))
        {
            lblUpdated.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["LabelUpdated"]);
            Session["LabelUpdated"] = null;
        }

        RadGrid1.ClientSettings.Scrolling.ScrollTop = "0";
        lblUpdated.Focus();
    }
```

I've since changed it to what is below:

```
    private void DisplayMessage()
    {
        // Display any messages from RadGrid2 that occurren in WebUserControl
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Session["LabelUpdated"])))
        {
            lblUpdated.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["LabelUpdated"]);
            Session["LabelUpdated"] = null;
            RadGrid1.ClientSettings.Scrolling.ScrollTop = "0";
            lblUpdated.Focus();
        }
    }
```

After the change the grid will only scroll to the top when a message is present from the WebUserControl.